# Get window id from javascript with help of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently I send message from my html page to chrome extension and it, in turn calls

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (win) {
     callback(win.id)
});
```

to get window Id. But if user selects another (or opens new) window just before this call, I get incorrect id. How can I get id of window, where my js code is running?

Comment: when exactly in the flow of your app do you run this code?

Comment: My current test.html has setInterval, which posts message to the extension to call getCurrent and return windowId. If I open new window, I see in my console that window id has changed. It means that getCurrent returns active window, but not window of test.html.

Comment: just store the last id of which the message should have been sent to and if the current id is different then do nothing? or wait until the user changes back.. maybe keep a queue of which message belongs to which window id

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your background script, you probably use `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){ ... }`

In that listener, you can use `sender.tab.windowId` to get the Id of the window that sent the message to the background script, regardless of the current active window.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. THANX!